# Flink SQL throw "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream" Error

Tags: apache-flink, presto, minio, flink-sql

I want to create a hudi table in my s3 storage,I followed the Official documentation, added these configuration in flink-conf.yml:

```
fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems: s3
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://flink/state/checkpoint
state.savepoints.dir: s3://flink/state/savepoint
s3.endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:9000
s3.path.style.access: true
s3.access-key: ****
s3.secret-key: ****
```

then copied **flink-s3-fs-presto-1.17.1.jar** to the **plugin** dir, **hudi-flink1.13-bundle-0.12.2.jar**  to the **lib** dir. After starting the flink-cluster, I used the sql-client to create a hudi table stored in s3:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  uuid VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  age INT,
  ts TIMESTAMP(3)
)
WITH (
  'connector' = 'hudi',
  'path' = 's3://hudi/tmp/test',
  'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ'
);
```

When I try to insert some data,I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
```